# Rationale for superclass reference to subclass object calls overriden method in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Example taken from [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/method-overriding-in-java-with-example/)

```
class Human{  
   //Overridden method  
   public void eat()  
   {  
      System.out.println("Human is eating");  
   }  
}  
class Boy extends Human{  
   //Overriding method  
   public void eat(){  
      System.out.println("Boy is eating");  
   }  
   public static void main( String args[]) {  
      Boy obj = new Boy();  
      //This will call the child class version of eat()  
      obj.eat();  
   }  
}
```

If we now create an Boy object with Human reference as:

```
Human boy = new Boy();
```

and call

```
boy.eat()
```

Why does it call eat() from Boy class rather than eat() from Human class. I know that methods from Boy class cannot be used when Human reference variable is used. So why does boy.eat() not call eat() from Human class?

Comment: Dynamic binding and polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Because boy is a reference variable of type Human whose value is an object of type Boy.

```
Human boy; // create a reference variable of type Human
boy = new Boy(); //  whose value is an object of type Boy
```

The right method to call is decided at runtime according to the object referred to :

- Compiler knows the type of boy is Human, so it checks Human has a eat() method
- At runtime, JVM discovers the value of boy is new Boy(), so it calls eat() method of Boy

Comment: Thanks! What is the rationale it is designed this way? Why would one want to limit the available methods to the super class except the ones which are overriden? Is there a good example?

Comment: It's called polymorphism and it's the essence of Java. I can't explain here this fundamental thing and the web overflow with explainations. But an example could be a method breathe() in Human class, called whenever the type of object (boy, baby, teenager or adult), so not overriden.

Comment: Yes I understand that. What I don't understand is why the limitation of the methods available when using reference variable of superclass only holds for methods which are not overriden.